# What should I do to develop a secure note taking app in Android 8.0?

Tags: passwords, android, memory

One of the factors I considered was, having all the text encrypted and stored in the device memory. But we cannot avoid having raw unencrypted data on the RAM, when the application runs. Won't Antivirus, and other system level processes have access to the contents in my application's memory? Is there a way to ensure that the app's runtime memory is not viewed or monitored by another application?

I want this application to work well on Samsung Galaxy on8 that runs Android  8.0.

The purpose of this is, I want to be able to store notes/data that I don't want even the phone manufacturers or Google (through the OS) to have access to its contents. I do understand that people with a requirement of security at this level, will have a custom built hardware. But I just want to create a super secure application as a project.

Comment: With the Android security model, properly stored application data cannot be accessed by other non-system applications. Of course, this model is violated by applications that have been granted root privileges. But what you are asking, to hide data from the OS, is not possible. Your only option would be to build a vanilla version of Android without Google or OEM features, but this assumes you completely trust the AOSP base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two goals are incompatible.

> I want this application to work well on [platform] that runs Android 8.0.

and

> Google (through the OS) to [not] have access to its contents.

"runs on Android 8.0" by definition means the OS (Android 8.0) will have access.

Assuming you want to do *minimize* that access, at the very least you will want to write your own keyboard. All those spell-check, auto-correct, and text prediction features are part of the OS, and the keyboard will have access to every key stroke you enter.

More reasonably, you probably shouldn't worry about RAM scrapers for memory, or the OS and keyboard, and just encrypt the bytes stored on disk for "good enough" protection.

Comment: For the keyboard, I might use this one: https://github.com/klausw/hackerskeyboard . But can you please tell me if there are any system level processes in Android 8.0 that captures the RAM data randomly and sends it to their servers for diagnostic purposes? Do Anti Viruses do this kind of job? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry. I don't know Android OS to that depth to answer specifically.